# Java minimax with strict time limit

Tags: java, recursion, time, timeout, limit

I am implementing an alpha beta search with iterative deepening for a board game for a school project. The only problem I have is strict time limit - the solution is not valid if it does not finish exactly on time. I have found multiple solutions to this problem, but none of them seems to work for me. Right now what I have is this:

```
public int act(int board[][], int[] moves, int timeLimit) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ActThread actThread = new ActThread(board, moves);
        Thread worker = new Thread(actThread);
        worker.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (0.9 * timeLimit));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println(e);

        }
        actThread.terminate();
        return actThread.getBestMove();
    }
```

As you can see I count the result in different thread, where is it counted with the use of iterative deepening. This is my simplest solution, but I have tried using ExecutorService, specifically awaitTermination function and I have tried to schedule TimerTask which will terminate the ActThread.

Comment: it would be better if you could explain what you are trying to achieve exactly

Comment: Depending on the time your work needs, you might be able to just use a interrupt flag. You can also check this flag in the middle of execution.

Comment: I have tried this, but it still takes some time to jump out of every recursive call.